# Image overlay showing IDs and not text

Tags: image, wordpress, overlay

In the post editor when you click on an image that has already been inserted an overlay pops up allowing you to edit the image.

This overlay is displaying things like {#cancel} instead of the word Cancel. All text on this overlay has been changed in a similar way.

Screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0151v82eb

I have disabled all plugins and performed an automatic reinstall of WordPress with no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like a language file is missing....

Comment: I have re-installed wordpress automatically & manually... still the same problem. I will have a look in the direction language files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading TinyMCE from their site and using the language files from the zip fixed the problem.

Found this link that might b helpful for others: http://e-mats.org/2008/07/tinymce-and-advanced_dlglink_url/